# Creating a dump file is excruciating slow

Tags: performance, windows-server-2008, dump, crash-dumps, procdump

**Brief**

Creating a dump file using any of the following methods is way to slow *(> 2 minutes)* to be usable for our current scenario.

- `procdump -ma notepad`
- `procdump notepad`
- Open task-manager, select notepad, create dump file

Does anyone have any idea

- what might be causing this
- how to possibly speed this up

**Edit: some extra information**

- Using procexp and looking at the call stack dumping notepad, it seems to be taking 100% cpu of one core in a method from dbghelp: `dbghelp.dll!MiniDumpReadDumpStream+0x241a`

*fortunatly, we tried this first with notepad*

**Background**

We are trying to create a dumpfile on a first-chance exception of a critical application with as minimal impact as possible. The application should not get suspended for more than a few seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this turned out to be related to the combination of our AV and a specific dbghelp.dll version.

**Tested combinations**

- AV Enabled with dbghelp version 6.0 is way to slow
- AV Disabled with dbghelp version 6.0 is no problem
- AV Enabled with dbghelp version 6.3 is no problem

[image: dbghelp.dll Versions tested]

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you may be requesting a full heap dump (.hdmp).  Full dumps tend to take longer.  If this is a one-off exercise, you can probably benefit from [capturing a minidump](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/how-to-capture-a-minidump-let-me-count-the-ways).  Otherwise, you would need to integrate a crash reporting strategy into your application.

Comment: I have tried capturing a minidump using task manager but it's no avail *(•Open task-manager, select notepad, create dump file)*